# No puedo usar Archivo.mdb despues de crearlo

Tags: vb.net

Estoy usando lo siguiente para crear un archivo **.mdb**, con una Tabla y datos. Pero al hacer Click en el **Button** para crearla, se crea también un archivo con extensión **.ldb** causante de que no puedo usar la Base De datos. Si hago Click en otro **Button** que activa un control **RadioButton** o cierro la aplicación el archivo con extensión **.ldb** desaparece. 
¿Pueden ayudarme a reescribir el código para que cuando lo aplique cierre completamente la DataBase y pueda usarla con codigo?

Muchas gracias.

```
Public Class NewProgreso

    ReadOnly pths As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)

    WithEvents Boton1 As New Button
    Public Sub Boton1_Click() Handles Boton1.Click
        MdbProgreso()
    End Sub

    Public Sub MdbProgreso()
        Dim stft = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = newpass;Data Source=" & pths & "\MiDb\Progreso.mdb;")

        Dim cnnx As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim ctlg As New ADOX.Catalog()

        Dim olcx As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand

        'CREAR ARCHIVO NUEVO
        If File.Exists(pths & "\MiDb\Progreso.mdb") Then
            File.Delete(pths & "\MiDb\Progreso.mdb")

            ctlg.Create(stft & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
        Else
            ctlg.Create(stft & ";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
        End If
        ctlg = Nothing

        'CREAR TABLAS"
        cnnx.Open(stft)
        cnnx.Execute("CREATE TABLE E5NC1 (Datos TEXT(10))")
        cnnx.Close()

        'CREAR DATOS"
        olcx.ConnectionString = stft

        olcx.Open()
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO E5NC1 (Datos) VALUES (0);"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = olcx
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdInsert.Dispose()
        olcx.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago así para conectar a las dbs , puedes ver si te funciona así como te lo envío ya me dirás algo

```
 CONECTAR.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Empresa.mdb"

Dim stft = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = newpass;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MiDb\Progreso.mdb"
```

Comment: Edita tu otro aporte y mejor ahí agrega esto o elimínalo por favor pues no hay necesidad de múltiples respuestas